# Optional multipart file upload with json?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, file-upload

I have an API that will do file uploading. In my api the file uploading should  be optional.if the user requesting without file along with the data the API should accept the request and save the data to DB. I have tried as follows :

```
@Transactional
    @RequestMapping(value = "/bugg-report", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    UserResponse fileUploaded(@RequestParam(required = true, value = "user_emailId") String email, @RequestParam(required = true, value = "category_id") String categoryId, @RequestParam(required = true, value = "subject") String subject, @RequestParam(required = true, value = "description") String description,
            @RequestParam(required = false, value = "uploadedFile") MultipartFile file) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        String status = "Failed";
        BugReport bugReport = null;
        UserResponse userResponse = new UserResponse();
        User user = null;
        int bugId = 0;
        try {
            user = loginService.getUser(email);
            if (user != null) {
                int userId = user.getProfileId();
                bugId = userDao.getLastBugReportId() + 1;
                bugReport = new BugReport();
                bugReport.setUserId(userId);
                bugReport.setCategoryId(Integer.parseInt(categoryId));
                bugReport.setBugSubject(subject);
                bugReport.setBugDescription(description);
                bugReport.setReportedDate(new Date());
                bugReport.setCurrentStatus(1);
                bugReport.setLastUpdatedDate(new Date());
                bugReport.setLastUpdatedUser(userId);
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                OutputStream outputStream = null;

                //MultipartFile file = uploadedFile.getFile();
                if (!file.isEmpty()) {
                    //   fileValidator.validate(uploadedFile, result);
                    String originalFileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
                    System.out.println("originalFileName = " + originalFileName);
//                    if (result.hasErrors()) {
//                        userResponse.setCode(WeekenterConstants.FAILURE_CODE);
//                        userResponse.setMessage("Failed try again");
//                        return userResponse;
//                    }

                    try {
                        inputStream = file.getInputStream();

                        String extension = "png";//Default
                        if (originalFileName != null) {
                            if (!originalFileName.equals("")) {
                                extension = Util.getExtension(originalFileName);
                            }
                        }
                        String filename = bugId + "." + extension;
                        File newFile = new File(WeekenterConstants.IMAGES_FOLDER);

                        if (!newFile.exists()) {
                            newFile.mkdirs();
                        }
                        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(newFile + "/" + filename);
                        int read = 0;
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

                        while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                            outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
                        }
                        inputStream.close();
                        outputStream.close();
                        bugReport.setImageName(filename);
                        userResponse.setCode(WeekenterConstants.SUCCESS_CODE);
                        userResponse.setMessage("Success");
                        userResponse.setEmail(email);
                        userResponse.setId(bugId);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        userResponse.setCode(WeekenterConstants.FAILURE_CODE);
                        userResponse.setEmail(email);
                        userResponse.setMessage("Failed try again");
                    }
                }
            } else {
                userResponse.setCode(WeekenterConstants.FAILURE_CODE);
                userResponse.setMessage("Invalid email id");
            }
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            userResponse.setCode(WeekenterConstants.FAILURE_CODE);
            userResponse.setMessage("Failed try again");
        }
        if (bugReport != null) {
            bugId = userDao.saveBugReport(bugReport);
            userResponse.setCode(WeekenterConstants.SUCCESS_CODE);
            userResponse.setEmail(email);
            userResponse.setMessage("Success");
            userResponse.setId(bugId);
        }
        return userResponse;
    }
```

But if I request without file it throwing

> Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: The current
>   request is not a multipart request

And also I need to know how we can send JSON request instead of passing parameters ?

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050333/upload-file-issue-with-spring-3-multipartexception-connection-reset

Comment: Thanks for your comment but it haven't related @aurelius

Comment: For starters check first if file is not null, don't check for not empty. And your code seems correct.

Comment: if am trying a normal request instead of send a multi part request even it will not entering inside the method itself..@We are Borg